# python multiple instantiation and passing values

Tags: python, class, instantiation

Newbie question. Can someone help me understand is happening below?

This is all from learn python the hard way ex43 - http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

How does the class Engine know what the first 'scene' in the list is from class Map? 
Where does that hand off occur?

I am also unsure on how the the Engine and the Map class communicate. I see it is instantiated at the bottom, but is it possible to have an instantiated object (a_map) then have that object be instantiated again (by a_game)?

Example:

```
a_map = Map('1')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
```

Here is the full code.

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('2')


        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)


class FristLevel(object):

    def enter(self):
    pass

class SecondLevel(object):

    def enter(self):
    pass

class Map(object):

    scenes = {'1' : FristLevel(),
    '2' : SecondLevel()}

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene


    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        pass

    def opening_scene(self):
        pass


a_map = Map('1')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but I'll try to break down the code for you a little. . .

```
a_map = Map('1')
```

This creates a new instance of `Map` and stores it in the name `a_map`.

```
a_game = Engine(a_map)
```

This creates a new instance of `Engine` and stores it in the name `a_game`.  Note that the input argument is `a_map`.  In this case, the `Map` instance gets passed to `Engine.__init__` and stored as the `scene_map` attribute.  In the example above, if you were to write:

```
a_game.scene_map is a_map
```

the result would be `True` because they are both names for the same `Map` instance.

Comment: Okay this helps, I was confused on how the variable a_game could call different items in the Map scenes list.

Comment: Therefore if I wanted to call an other item from Map.scenes list from the engine how can I do that?